# How to successfully login and move to another view using php web service

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

Firstly I have two text fields first is login and second is password and one login button. I am using a storyboard and login button connected to another view controller by push segue.
This time working in my project, Put username and password in textfield and select login button after move another view. I entered the wrong password login is still and move another view. I think somewhere condition is wrong.
please help how exactly do I do. thank you

I follow this tutorial [Dipin Krishna Tutorial](https://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2013/12/ios-login-screen-tutorial-xcode-5-ios-7-storyboard-json/)

## my code is

```
- (IBAction)loginac:(id)sender {
    NSInteger success = 0;
    @try {
        
        if([[self.txfld text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.tx1 text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
            
            [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Email and Password" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
            
        } else {
            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[self.txfld text],[self.tx1 text]];
            NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);
            
            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dipinkrishna.com/jsonlogin.php"];
            
            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            
            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
            
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];
            
            //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];
            
            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
            
            NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
            
            if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
            {
                NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
                
                NSError *error = nil;
                NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                          JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                          error:&error];
                
                success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];
                NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);
                
                if(success == 1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                } else {
                    
                    NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                    [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
                }
                
            } else {
                //if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException * e) {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
    }

    if (success) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
    }
}

- (void) alertStatus:(NSString *)msg :(NSString *)title :(int) tag
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                        message:msg
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    alertView.tag = tag;
    [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: you are in the corect way need a small modification

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks for replay, where to need a small modification

Comment: I posted the answer check once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this

```
if (success) {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];

}
```

and add to inside of `SUCCESS` condition , surely works

```
 if(success == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
        }
```

**for full Answer**

```
- (IBAction)loginac:(id)sender {


    if([[self.txfld text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[self.tx1 text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {

        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter Email and Password" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];

    } else {
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[self.txfld text],[self.tx1 text]];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://dipinkrishna.com/jsonlogin.php"];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);

        if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300)
        {


            NSError *error = nil;
            NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                      error:&error];

          int success = [jsonData[@"success"] integerValue];


            if(success == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
            } else {

                NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
            }

        } else {
            //if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: I follow your condition but  I entered the wrong password login is still and move another view.

Comment: same issue create how it possible.

Comment: I am using navigation controller

Comment: CAN YOU ATTACH THE PROJECT I WILL CHECK

Comment: I tryed blank text field and click login button this condition still move another view

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - you no need that correct, only after the webservice call you need correct

Comment: Please download and check

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - problem Solved

Comment: How, solution is where?

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - you can download the project in here https://www.dropbox.com/s/gzi6kxo9n0hzlja/new1%202.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thankyou so much desar sir. its working properly. :)

Comment: @AnkurKumawat - compare once in stroyboard what the diference in your connection and my connection,